# Explain this UTF-8 detection regex

Tags: php, regex

This question asked how to detect UTF-8 strings - [How to detect if have to apply utf8 decode or encode on a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4407854/)

The solution was this:

```
if (preg_match('!!u', $string))
{
   // this is utf-8
}
else 
{
   // definitely not utf-8
}
```

I haven't been able to figure out how to breakdown the "!!u" expression. I clicked through all of PHP's PCRE stuff and might have missed the description for "!" marks and "u"-somethings. I tried running it through perl's YAPE::Regex::Explain (as seen in [Please explain this Perl regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/381157/please-explain-this-perl-regular-expression/381175#381175)) and couldn't get something that made sense [I'm no perl expert - don't know if I fed it the right expression/string].

So... how exactly does `preg_match('!!u', $string)` work?

Comment: Did you check the comments for that answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's just an empty regular expression. `!` is the [delimiter](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) and `u` is the [modfier](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php).

As for why it works, from PHP Manual's description of the `u` modifier (emphasis mine):

> This modifier turns on additional functionality of PCRE that is incompatible with Perl. Pattern strings are treated as UTF-8. This modifier is available from PHP 4.1.0 or greater on Unix and from PHP 4.2.3 on win32. **UTF-8 validity of the pattern is checked** since PHP 4.3.5.

Answer (score 5):

The `!` is being used as the delimiter instead of `/`. I'll rewrite this for you, `//u` is the same thing. The `u` is a modifier that treats the pattern as utf8.